# What is the safest way to use a password in a Programm

Tags: aes, delphi-10.2-tokyo, secret-key

in my program I create a AES 128 encrypted key. To do so, first I use a masterkey, thats only written inside of the Code, I write that string directly through the AES 128 function. No var is set for that. After that I salt it with another uniq/random key.

My Question is, is there a safer way for masterkey? Would it be possible to extract that key from compiled program? Of course the Function for AES have to store the value in a string to handle it. Is there some sort of "best practice"?

Comment: Anything can be extracted with enough effort. Since your app uses it, if someone really wants it, they will figure out how to get it, so all you can do is make it hard for them to do that. In my own apps, I calculate my encryption master key dynamically at runtime using a multi-loop random number algorithm with a fixed seed so the resulting key is fixed but does not exist in the app's compiled code itself. Then other keys are derived when needed using a combination of the master key, user provided passwords, and random salts.

Comment: that sounds crazy :-o what do you mean with "multi-loop random number algorithm" how do you get a fixed key by using random numbers?

Comment: The RNG is called in a loop many times, but the initial RNG seed is fixed every time a new loop is run, so the result is always the same.